# Vagrant RDP => Windows2012R2 | How do I rdp into my vagrant box?

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

```
➜  ~  vagrant rdp
==> default: Detecting RDP info...
    default: Address: 127.0.0.1:3389
    default: Username: vagrant
==> default: Vagrant will now launch your RDP client with the connection parameters
==> default: above. If the connection fails, verify that the information above is
==> default: correct. Additionally, make sure the RDP server is configured and  
==> default: running in the guest machine (it is disabled by default on Windows).
==> default: Also, verify that the firewall is open to allow RDP connections.
```

[image: 1]

I'm using `(vagrant box add) mwrock/Windows2012R2 --provider virtualbox`

What else am I missing? How do I RDP into my vm?

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but seeing as how it's one of the top results in google I'll provide a recent answer.

Tested with:

- Host: macOS 10.13.6 (High Sierra)
- VM: Windows 10 1803 (RS4)
- vagrant 2.1.5
- Microsoft Remote Desktop 10.2.1

Steps:

1. Configure `Vagrantfile` for Windows VM with RDP forwarded:

   ```
   config.vm.guest = :windows
   config.vm.communicator = "winrm"
   config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3389, host: 3389
   ```
2. Enable Remote Desktop.  In the VM:

   - Start > Settings > Remote Desktop > Enable Remote Desktop
3. Install an RDP client

   - On Mac this would be [Microsoft Remote Desktop 10](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id1295203466?mt=12)

When you `vagrant up` should see something similar to:

```
==> default: Forwarding ports...
  default: 3389 (guest) => 3389 (host) (adapter 1)
```

Then `vagrant rdp` should launch Remote Desktop and connect to the VM.

Comment: And what do I type under `config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|` to actually run the rdp , serve rdp from vb